# I use Amazon S3 for storage. How can I create a backup of that data?

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

What is the most efficient way to backup data store in Amazon's S3 service?

1. is it to copy to another bucket? What are some tools for doing this? or should I just code for it?
2. is it to copy to another service?
3. or just copy an archive in a data center? Is there an easy way to do it incrementally?
4. Amazon has a system for you to send them a drive but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Isn't the idea with S3 that they provide the data redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the data to another bucket is not going to properly cover the case where Amazon loses your data.  You'd need to either dump the data from S3, or write out a local copy when writing to S3, and then archive that in a separate location.  The S3 export functionality is one way of dumping that data.

As with many things, it ultimately depends on the requirements for your app.